# What is the difference between transpiration and evapotranspiration?

Tags: botany, physiology

According to my point of view transpiration and evapotranspiration are different things, but i am confused about this topic. After great effort, I found a major difference between it.

**Transpiration**: The loss of water in the form of vapour from plants surface is called transpiration.

**Evapotranspiration**: The loss of water from any surface in the form of vapour is called evapotranspiration. Such as water surface, soil and any body surface.
By [educationspot](https://educationspot.net)

Is it correct? Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, evapotranspiration is the sum of evaporation and plant transpiration from the Earth's land and ocean surface to the atmosphere.

[image: Evapotranspiration]

Here are some links to articles about transpiration: https://biolympiads.com/plant-anatomy-and-physiology/